# Why am I getting 404 /N2/Api/Context.ashx

Tags: n2cms

I'm using the NuGet N2CMS package. I've tried version 2.9.6.8 and 2.9.6.14( and .16)

This is a fresh setup/install. When finishing the setup and navigating to /N2 I'm getting a 404 Not Found from the following:

/N2/API/Context.ash?mode=full
[image]

You can see my question on their GitHub [here](https://github.com/n2cms/n2cms/issues/764).

Anyone experience this, or have a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bherila from the N2CMS team, was able to help me. It turns out that some of the Nuget Packages do not work out of the box; one of which is the standalone N2CMS package.

I was able to get a new project working using the N2CMS.NoZip (management UI) and N2CMS.MVC packages.

Even with these, you will still need to create and decorate a RootPage and StartPage to get past installation. You can see how I created those in the link I posted in my question